# I need to put in a script an id with zero value

Tags: mysql, sql

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS home (
  id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  description(200) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 COLLATE=latin1_bin;
```

I need to insert a default value with id=0 but, I can't in this way. Anyone can help me?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have a DEFAULT value on an AUTOINCREMENT column. Also, as ID is your primary key, it would not really make sense to have a DEFAULT.

If you are just trying to insert an ID with a « 0 » value : mysql by default does not allow this on an AUTOINCREMENT field, but this can be tweaked with :

```
SET [GLOBAL|SESSION] sql_mode='NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO'
```

However this is not recommended. See [the mysql docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_no_auto_value_on_zero)

Answer (score 0):

I would be very cautious about trying to do such a thing.  MySQL is so adamant about keeping zeros out that it *changes* the values of `0` to `1` when a column becomes an auto-increment column.  Consider what happens with this code:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS home (
  id int(11) NOT NULL,
  description varchar(200) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1;

insert into home (id, description)
    values (0, 'my home');

select *
from home;

alter table home modify column id int auto_increment;

select *
from home;
```

The table no longer has `0` after the `alter table`.

Presumably, this is because long ago MySQL decided that `0` is a signal for using the default value, so the value is baked in.

You *can* use any other value that you want.  So you might consider `-1` if you want a "default" values for your tables that use `auto_increment`.

Comment: it doesn't work because when I check the values in the date are id=1 and my home. There are another method?

Comment: @poopp . . . That was my point.  MySQL changes the value (I think the answer is clear on this point).  If you want a special value, you can use `-1`.